# Compiled child directive is appended to parent but can't access parent scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created 2 directive one for displaying box(`confirmedBox` directive) and one for showing that box (confirmingBox). Inside link function of `confirmingBox`, I've created `confirmedBox` by compiling with parent scope is `confirmingBox`. However, when click on "Show box" button, it log isDisplay `undefined`, which means I can't do 2 way binding for variable isDisplay from the parent to child directives. I don't know why it've not worked?

Code live:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SHH1JEtGJxibyem25kfd?p=preview

Code javascript:

```
angular.module('AppA2_Task',[])
.directive('confirmedClick', function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.displayBox = true;
            element.on('click', function () {
                element.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                var boxScope = $rootScope.$new(true, scope);
                var boxElem = $compile('<div data-confirming-box data-confirm="confirm" data-is-displayed="displayBox"></div>')(boxScope);
                element.append(boxElem);
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.displayBox = true;
                });
            });
        }
    }
})
.directive('confirmingBox', function () {
    return {
        //require: '^confirmedClick',
        restrict: 'A',
        template: "<div ng-if='isDisplayed'>I am a box</div>",
        scope: {
            isDisplayed: '='
        },
        link : function(scope){
          console.log('isDisplayed',scope.isDisplayed);
        }
    }
})
.controller('MainController', function () {

});
```

Code html

```
<body data-ng-controller="MainController">
    <button data-confirmed-click>Show box</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are linking the template with `boxScope`, but setting `displayBox = true` on `scope`.

Change it to:

```
boxScope.displayBox = true;
```

You also need to do this before compiling and linking, or it will be `undefined` when the link function of `confirmingBox` executes.

Lastly, either call `scope.$apply()` without arguments at the end, or wrap everything in the click function with it.

I prefer the second alterantive since Angular will then internally wrap it in a `try...catch` block, and any exceptions that occur will be passed to the `$exceptionHandler` service.

Example:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  element.on('click', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      element.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      var boxScope = $rootScope.$new(true, scope);
      boxScope.displayBox = true;
      var boxElem = $compile('<div data-confirming-box data-confirm="confirm" data-is-displayed="displayBox"></div>')(boxScope);
      element.append(boxElem);
    });
  });
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/OwcgD0NntVo3DhTVvXmA?p=preview

Comment: It seem that I must use scope instead of boxScope when compiling, and when compiling boxElem will have it own scope. Thanks.